# How to unset or set default radio button value programmatically?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, commerce

I'm using Commerce Kickstart and I have a term reference for Size field of my product variation, and I'm using the Check boxes/radio buttons widget with commerce fancy attributes.

Currently, when I'm in the Product Display page, it seems that the default value set to *Large*. Since I don't want to insult my users by appearing to think that they are all "*Large*", I would like to set the default value to "S"

I'm using the following code to target all the commerce add to cart forms, with reference to an answer from here: Commerce - Theme Add-to-Cart form on Product Display page

```
function MODULENAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  // Add to cart form overrides
  if(substr($form_id, 0, 30) == 'commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form'){
    $form['attributes']['field_size']['#default_value'] = VALUE
    $form['unchanged_attributes']['field_size']['#value'] = '13';
    //where VALUE is chosen from $form['attributes']['field_size']['#options']
  }
}
```

**Despite the fact that *Small* is highlighted as a result, when I press "Add to cart", size "L" gets added to the cart by default.**

(When I click a value, such as "M", size "M" gets added to cart as expected, it is only the default value that is buggy)

> [image]

> [image]

This is my `dpm($form)` for reference.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: Just keep the value required when you create  the field and remove the default value if it is there

Comment: I am not sure what problem you are seeing. The default value I see set in the second screenshot is 13, which is the value associated to _S_. What are you expecting to see as default value? _S_? If that is the case, then it is not how Drupal works

Comment: Also, it is the Devel module that writes _(callback) L()_, but the _#options_ values are not callbacks. They are just strings that appear in the UI; they are not taken as being callbacks, from Drupal.

Comment: I am going to close this question until you don't make clear what you mean by _callback value_ in "the callback value is not changed." There aren't callbacks involved, in the code you are showing.

Comment: Actually my real problem was that when I press "Add to cart", size "L" gets added to the cart by default, despite the fact that the default value was set to 13 or S. I thought that it was due to the callback but I was merely guessing. I appreciate any help you may offer me that would help me understand this problem. Thanks! (When I click a value, such as "M", size "M" gets added to cart as expected, it is only the default value that is buggy). I have edited my question.

Comment: Hi, I've edited out the parts of the question where I wrote about callbacks. Is it ok now?

Comment: If it's still unclear, I would appreciate some comments as to why so that I can improve it, please.